# SharePoint Add-in permission

Tags: sharepoint-online

There is a option in the App Catalog to share an app. We can select Can Edit option and share. But I could not find what actually happens when you do this. Where does this permission get affected?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "Apps for SharePoint" is another type of document library which contains your app package. The "Share" menu item should be the same one as the list item or document which provides item level permission management. You can configure the specific apps to be accessed by specific users for specific actions, like edit if you don't want your apps to inherit from default "App for SharePoint" library's permission sets.